# Find $\int_0^{+\infty}\cos 2x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\frac{x}{n}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, infinite-product

Evaluate the following integral

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\cos 2x\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\frac{x}{n}dx$$

I was thinking of a way which do not need to explicitly find the closed form of the infinite product, since I don't have any idea to tackle that. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: do you know this integral even converges?

Comment: @IgorRivin I was reading   http://www.calpoly.edu/~kmorriso/Research/cosine.pdf    The numerical analysis tells this integral does converge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral 
$$g(y)={1\over \pi}\int_0^\infty \cos(xy)\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos{x\over n}\,dx$$
is the density function of a random variable that I call the [Random Harmonic Series](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/rhs.pdf).
The value $g(2)$ is particularly interesting as it is almost, but not quite equal, $1/8$.

To  fifty decimal places, it is 
$$g(2)=.12499999999999999999999999999999999999999976421683.$$
If you read my paper, you will discover why it is so close to $1/8$.

---

Random harmonic series. *American Mathematical Monthly* 110, 407-416 (May 2003).

Comment: Actually I was just reading your paper, not knowing that you are the author! I googled your paper with the keyword *random harmonic series*, for I know they are related, considering the formula $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos \theta_{k} = \Bbb{E}\cos\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\varepsilon_{k}\theta_{k}\right)$$ with $\varepsilon_{k}$ being independent random signs.

Comment: Wow! That is more than I expected! Thank you for providing the reference and for sure I'll read through it.

Comment: @Max No problem!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is to evaluate $$\prod_{i=0}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{2^i}.$$ Note that if you go to $k,$ instead of $\infty,$ the standard trick of multiplying the product by $\sin \frac{x}{2^k}$ gives you

$$\prod_{i=0}^k \cos\frac{x}{2^i} = \frac1{2^k}\frac{\sin 2 x}{\sin \frac{x}{2^k}}.$$
Taking the limit as $k$ goes to infinity, gives you

$$\prod_{i=0}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{2^i} = \frac{\sin{2 x}}{x}.$$ This tells you that the whole product (over all integers) equals to 
$$\prod_{\mbox{odd integers}} \frac{\sin (2x/n)}{x/n}.$$

At this point I admit to be stuck, but I am sure Kent Morrison's paper cited by the OP sheds light on this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Kent Morrison's papers on the topic are a joy to read!

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Kent is a good guy, no doubt about it.